# Insert one bash script into another

Tags: bash, shell

I have two `bash` scripts: main one and auxiliary.

Let's say main script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is start of my main script"
./auxiliary.sh
echo "This is end of my main script"
```

and auxiliary one is:

```
cd some-folder
echo "This is file placed in some-folder by auxiliary script" > file1
cd ..
cd other-folder
echo "This is file placed in other-folder by auxiliary script" > file2
```

My goal is to execute lines in auxiliary script (or just text file) as if those lines were written directly in main script. So if, for example, I invoke `auxiliary.sh` from inside a loop or function, all lines of auxiliary.sh will be executed in that loop or function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.` command (alternately available as `source` in `bash`):

```
echo "This is the start of my main script"
# . ./auxiliary.sh
source ./auxiliary.sh
echo "This is the end of my main script"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the `bash script` into another using the `.` command.

Comment: Can you given an example?